# Ubuntu 14.04 brightness preference option

Tags: brightness

The lighting preference option seems to allow increased lighting adjustment but after re-setting the screen darkens! When I check the setting it has returned to the previous position. Is there a terminal control command that I can use?

Answer (score 0):

To set screen brightness or gamma options you can use **xrandr**

I use below commands for that purpose:

```
 xrandr --output LVDS1 --brightness 1.4

 xrandr --output LVDS1 --gamma 0.5:1.0:1.0
```

LVDS1 is type of my monitor. You can find yours with :

```
 xrandr
```

You can also use **xbacklight** like

```
 xbacklight -set 90
```

Comment: thank you! Is there a command to activate my laptop internal wi-fi?